# SASS Syntax error: Expected a Number. Got: calc()

Tags: css, sass

When I use this CSS in the browser, it works fine

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), red 50%, transparent calc(50% + 1px) );
```

But when I use it in SASS,

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1px), red 50%, transparent calc(50% + 1px) )
```

I get an error: `SASS Syntax error: Expected a Number. Got: calc(50% + 1px)`
What am I missing?

Comment: what compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using Babel.